# REGEX to remove a string surrounded by < pikes >

Tags: c#, regex, string

What would be a `c#` regular expression to replace all text/characters between an opening and closing pike?

For example:

```
this is an <example> that <needs> to turn into

=> this is an that to turn into
```

Comment: Could you include your attempt thus far?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of Regex, I would use Html parsers like [HtmlAgilityPack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) for that

```
string html = "this is an <example> that <needs> to turn into";
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
var text = doc.DocumentNode.InnerText;
```

But if you have to use Regex

```
var text = Regex.Replace(html, @"\<.+\>", String.Empty);
```

Comment: Why use an HTML parser if it isn't HTML?